# Blender liquid Simulator too little blue particles

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have a domain liquid and flow liquid. But unlike tutorials the blue particles are just barely visible drops of water instead of the splash.

I tried scaling then apply transform for the cube size. Nothing worked. Why is that?

[Download .blend](https://www.mediafire.com/file/fcmefikmrawl4mp/LiquidTest.blend/file)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make "blue" particles visible ...

- select *Domain* object
- go to *Particles Properties* > select *Liquid* from the list > *Viewport Display* panel and increase *Size*

[image]

The reason why you see just a ten particles lays under *Liquid Properties > System Maximum* > set zero to see "splash" ...

[image]

Anyway you operate in a huge dimension, Scale is not applied and when set Scale to 1 than Domain Dimension is 500 m ... it can probably generate some issues too. Also for sims is better keep object's Origin in geometry centre.

Comment: Awesome! Super thanks dude. I have much to learn. :D